# Javascript: Deserialize object and mix-in methods

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

In Javascript, I'm currently using `localStorage`. As it's not possible to put in objects, I'm `JSON.stringify`-ing them before.

I'm storing an entire game state, and some few of the sub-objects have methods.

When reading them back using `JSON.parse`, the methods are gone - which makes absolutely sense. Would be dumb to store the object including methods in the browser.

What is the best way to "reattach" the methods to the object that it has had before, so that the object can behave the same way it did before?

Is it a good way to just do

```
savedObj.prototype = MyClass.prototype;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It depends. If any object had any instance-specific functions, then restoring prototype only is not enough. Also, only setting a prototype will not set up a proper inheritance, so `instanceof` will not work as well. So you need `savedObj.__proto__ = MyClass.prototype;` additionally

Comment: You are missing an example of your original object.

Comment: Store the relevant info in key, values and in the methods read their values IF they exist

Comment: @zerkms: Thank you. Well I don't really care about `instanceof` or instance-specific functions (they don't have any.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to do something like this?

Javascript

```
function MyClass(state) {
    if (typeof state === 'string') {
        this.state = JSON.parse(state);
    } else {
        this.state = {};
    }

    this.appendChild = function (element) {
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.toJSON()));
    }
}

MyClass.prototype = {
    log: function () {
        console.log(this.toJSON());

        return this;
    },
    set: function (key, value) {
        this.state[key] = value;

        return this;
    },
    toJSON: function () {
        return JSON.stringify(this.state);
    }
};

var myClass1 = new MyClass();

myClass1.set('somekey', true);
myClass1.log();

localStorage.mySave = myClass1.toJSON();

var myClass2 = new MyClass(localStorage.mySave);

myClass2.log();
myClass2.appendChild(document.body);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/6yqjz5d6/)